# "Job was Cancelled" Android Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my app, there is an EditText that shows date picker dialog and also a spinner. The spinner item contains data from database that is filled after date is set.

It was working normal until in some occasion that I couldn't replicate the error, it shows "Job was cancelled" in Logcat. And when it happened, the spinner is empty.

Here is my fragment code

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"
private var isMandatory : Boolean? = true


class AddReportFragment : Fragment(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddReportBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: AddReportViewModel
    private lateinit var sptransactionType: Spinner
    private lateinit var spMandatory: Spinner
    private lateinit var spNonMandatory: Spinner


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentAddReportBinding.inflate(inflater)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AddReportViewModel::class.java)
        val spBookName : Spinner = binding.spBookName
        spMandatory = binding.spMandatory
        spNonMandatory = binding.spNonMandatory
        sptransactionType = binding.sptransactionType

        viewModel.bookName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                var string : String = ""
                val listArr = arrayListOf<String>()
                for (i in 0 .. it.size - 1){
                    string = it.get(i).bookName
                    listArr.add(string)
                }
                ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArr)
                    .also { adapter ->
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                        spBookName.adapter = adapter
                    }
            }
        })

        binding.etPeriode.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            if(v.hasFocus()){
                val showDialog = ShowDatePickerDialog()
                showDialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "Show Date Picker")
            }
        }

        sptransactionType.onItemSelectedListener = this
        spBookName.onItemSelectedListener = this
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        if(parent!!.id == R.id.spBookName) {
            val selected = parent.selectedItem
            viewModel.getBookType(selected.toString())
            viewModel.bookType.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    if (it.get(0).bookType == "Mandatory") {
                        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(requireContext(), R.array.transactionType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
                            .also { adapter ->
                                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                                sptransactionType.adapter = adapter
                            }
                        isMandatory = true
                    } else if (it.get(0).bookType == "Non Mandatory") {
                        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(requireContext(), R.array.transactionType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
                            .also { adapter ->
                                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                                sptransactionType.adapter = adapter
                            }
                        isMandatory = false
                    }
                    viewModel.resetBookType()
                }

            })

            viewModel.getMandatoryName(selected.toString())
            viewModel.getNonMandatoryName(selected.toString())
            viewModel.mandatoryName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    var string : String = ""
                    val listArr = arrayListOf<String>()
                    for(i in 0 .. it.size -1){
                        string = it.get(i).name
                        listArr.add(string)
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArr)
                        .also { adapter ->
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                            spMandatory.adapter = adapter
                        }
                }
            })

            viewModel.nonMandatoryName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    var string : String = ""
                    val listArr = arrayListOf<String>()
                    for(i in 0 .. it.size -1){
                        string = it.get(i).name
                        listArr.add(string)
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArr)
                        .also { adapter ->
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                            spNonMandatory.adapter = adapter
                        }
                }
            })
        }else if (parent.id == R.id.sptransactionType){
            val selected = parent.selectedItem
            if(selected == "Plus" && isMandatory == true) {
                binding.spMandatory.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.spNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.setText("")
            }else if(selected == "Minus" && isMandatory == true){
                binding.spMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.spNonMandatory.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.setText("")
            }else if(selected == "Minus" && isMandatory == false){
                binding.spMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.spNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.setText("")
            }else if(selected == "Plus" && isMandatory == false){
                binding.spMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.spNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.setText("")
            }else{
                binding.spMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.spNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.etNameNonMandatory.setText("")
            }
        }
    }



    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
       
    }

class ShowDatePickerDialog() : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        return DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, year, month, day)
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        val periode = requireActivity().findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etPeriode)
        val spNonMandatory: Spinner = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.spNonMandatory)
        val spMandatory: Spinner = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.spMandatory)
        val spBookName: Spinner = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.spBookName)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AddReportViewModel::class.java)
        val month = month + 1
        val givenDate = "$dayOfMonth $month $year"
        val givenDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy")
        val givenDateParse = givenDateFormat.parse(givenDate)
        val resultGivenDate = givenDateParse.time

        val givenMonth = "$month"
        val givenMonthFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM")
        val givenMonthParse = givenMonthFormat.parse(givenMonth)
        val resultGivenMonth = givenMonthParse.time

        val monthNow = SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(Date())
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM")
        val toMil = dateFormat.parse(monthNow)
        val result = toMil.time

        if(resultGivenMonth == result){
            viewModel.getMandatoryName(spBookName.selectedItem.toString())
            viewModel.getNonMandatoryName(spBookName.selectedItem.toString())
            viewModel.mandatoryName.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    var string : String = ""
                    val listArr = arrayListOf<String>()
                    for(i in 0 .. it.size -1){
                        string = it.get(i).name
                        listArr.add(string)
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArr)
                        .also { adapter ->
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                            spMandatory.adapter = adapter
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                }
            })

            viewModel.nonMandatoryName.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    var string : String = ""
                    val listArr = arrayListOf<String>()
                    for(i in 0 .. it.size -1){
                        string = it.get(i).name
                        listArr.add(string)
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArr)
                        .also { adapter ->
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                            spNonMandatory.adapter = adapter
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                }
            })

        }else if(resultGivenMonth != result){
            viewModel.getAll(spBookName.selectedItem.toString())
            viewModel.getAll.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    var string : String = ""
                    val listArr = arrayListOf<String>()
                    for(i in 0 .. it.size -1){
                        string = it.get(i).warga
                        listArr.add(string)
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArr)
                        .also { adapter ->
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                            spNonMandatory.adapter = adapter
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }

                    ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArr)
                        .also { adapter ->
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                            spMandatory.adapter = adapter
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                }
            })
//            viewModel.resetGetAll()
        }

        periode.setText(SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(resultGivenDate))
    }

}
```

And ViewModel code

```
class AddReportViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _bookName = MutableLiveData<List<GetBookName>>()
val bookName: LiveData<List<GetBookName>>
    get() = _bookName

private val _mandatoryName = MutableLiveData<List<GetMandatoryName>>()
val mandatoryName: LiveData<List<GetMandatoryName>>
    get() = _mandatoryName

private val _nonMandatoryName = MutableLiveData<List<GetNonMandatoryName>>()
val nonMandatoryName: LiveData<List<GetNonMandatoryName>>
    get() = _nonMandatoryName

private val _bookType = MutableLiveData<List<GetBookType>>()
val bookType: LiveData<List<GetBookType>>
    get() = _bookType

private val _getAll = MutableLiveData<List<GetAll>>()
val getAll: LiveData<List<GetAll>>
    get() = _getAll


init {
    getBookName()
}

private fun getBookName() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val bookName = Ebook.retrofitService.getBookName()
            _bookName.value = bookName
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            _bookName.value = ArrayList()
        }
    }
}

fun getBookType(bookName: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val bookType = Ebook.retrofitService.getBookType(bookName)
            _bookType.value = bookType
        }catch (exception: Exception){
            _bookType.value = ArrayList()
        }
    }
}

fun getMandatoryName(bookName: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try{
            val mandatoryName = Ebook.retrofitService.getMandatory(bookName)
            _mandatoryName.value = mandatoryName
        }catch (exception: Exception){
            Log.e("Exception Message", exception.message.toString())
            Log.e("Exception Message", exception.cause.toString())
        }
    }
}

fun getNonMandatoryName(bookName: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try{
            val nonMandatoryName = Ebook.retrofitService.getNonMandatory(bookName)
            _nonMandatoryName.value = nonMandatoryName
        }catch (exception: Exception){
            Log.e("Exception Message", exception.message.toString())
            Log.e("Exception Message", exception.cause.toString())
        }
    }
}

fun resetBookType(){
    _bookType.value = null
}

fun getAll(bookName: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try{
            val getAll = Ekomplek.retrofitService.getAllBayar(bookName)
            _getAll.value = getAll
        }catch (exception: Exception){
            Log.e("Exception Message", exception.message.toString())
        }
    }
}

fun resetGetAll(){
    _getAll.value = null
}

fun resetDonaturDebetKredit(){
    _mandatoryName.value = null
    _nonMandatoryName.value = null
}
}
```

As you can see, here on override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int), I'm doing a check whether month now is the same as the month that is selected from date picker dialog. If it's the same, the spinner is filled with a filtered data from database that is matched with the month. And if month now is not the same as the month that is selected, the spinner is filled with all data from database.

Rarely, after I set the date, it shows "Job was cancelled" and the spinner is blank. Most of the time it works, though.

Is there anyway I fix this?

P.S. the same coroutine is also used in other fragments. Even in class AddReportFragment, that coroutine is also used. Everything was fine. No "Job was cancelled". I don't know why sometimes it doesn't work on DatePickerDialog class

Comment: Which function is throwing this exception?

Comment: It's random. Sometimes getMandatoryName, or getNonMandatoryName, or getAll()